# PHP array referencing issue

Tags: php, arrays

I am ignorant to what is happening!

Here is the error:

```
Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xxxx\htdocs\xxxxx\xxxxx\class.mysql.php on line 51

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Invocation of method mysqli_stmt::bind_param() failed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\assemblyx.net\class\class.mysql.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\xxxx\htdocs\xxxxx\xxxxx\class.mysql.php(51): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(mysqli_stmt), Array) #1 C:\xxxx\htdocs\xxxxx\xxxxx\index.php(17): mysql->Insert('test', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xxxx\htdocs\xxxxx\xxxxx\class.mysql.php on line 51
```

Code in `index.php`:

```
$a=array();
$a[0]=array();
$a[0]["test_value"]="helloMysqli";
$a[0]["test_int"]="2";
$a[0]["test_dec"]="3.1";
$db->Insert("test", $a);
```

Method in `class.mysql.php`:

```
function Insert($table, $arrInsert){
    $types = $cols = $q = "";
    $value = array();
    foreach($arrInsert as $k => $v){
        foreach($v as $k2 => $v2){
            $cols .= ($cols=="")?$k2:", ".$k2;
            $q .= ($q=="")?"?":", ?";
            $value[] = $v2;
            $types .= substr(gettype($v2),0,1);
        }
    }
    $sql = "insert into ".$table." (".$cols.") value (".$q.");";
    $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);

    $refArr = array();
    $refArr[0] = $types;
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        $refArr[] = $v;
    }

    $ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
    $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");
    $method->invokeArgs($stmt,$refArr); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Now if I code the array into the `Insert` method every works fine:

```
function Insert($table, $arrInsert){
    $types = $cols = $q = "";
    $value = array();
    foreach($arrInsert as $k => $v){
        foreach($v as $k2 => $v2){
            $cols .= ($cols=="")?$k2:", ".$k2;
            $q .= ($q=="")?"?":", ?";
            $value[] = $v2;
            $types .= substr(gettype($v2),0,1);
        }
    }
    $sql = "insert into ".$table." (".$cols.") value (".$q.");";
    $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);

    $refArr = array();
    $refArr[] = $types;
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        $refArr[] = $v;
    }
//****************
// added array here
//*****************     
    $refArr = array();
    $refArr[] = "sss";
    $refArr[] = "helloMysqli";
    $refArr[] = "2";
    $refArr[] = "3.1";

    $ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
    $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");
    $method->invokeArgs($stmt,$refArr); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I am obviosly not understanding how the array is being referenced. Please someone enlighten me!

Here are the print_r outputs to show that both arrays are outputting the same:

```
    function Insert($table, $arrInsert){
        $types = $cols = $q = "";
        $value = array();
        foreach($arrInsert as $k => $v){
            foreach($v as $k2 => $v2){
                $cols .= ($cols=="")?$k2:", ".$k2;
                $q .= ($q=="")?"?":", ?";
                $value[] = $v2;
                $types .= substr(gettype($v2),0,1);
            }
        }
        $sql = "insert into ".$table." (".$cols.") value (".$q.");";
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);

        $refArr = array();
        $refArr[] = $types;
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            $refArr[] = $v;
        }
        print_r($refArr);
        exit;

// print_r output : Array ( [0] => sss [1] => helloMysqli [2] => 2 [3] => 3.1 )

        $refArr = array();
        $refArr[] = "sss";
        $refArr[] = "helloMysqli";
        $refArr[] = "2";
        $refArr[] = "3.1";


// print_r output : Array ( [0] => sss [1] => helloMysqli [2] => 2 [3] => 3.1 )



        $ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
        $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");
        $method->invokeArgs($stmt,$refArr); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: If you do a `print_r($value);` prior to the `foreach()` loop `foreach($value as $k => $v){`.... what are you seeing? It would be nice to know that you did some kind of error checking prior to just tossing a question up here.

Comment: I did a `var_dump` on both arrays, they both returned the exact same value, is `var_dump` equivalent to `print_r`?

Comment: `print_r` is "human readable", but what comes back form those arrays? It could be that your `foreach` loop is incorrect but again, we can't help without knowing what you are seeing.

Comment: I have tested this over and over, they both bring back the exact same result, just did a `print_r` : `Array ( [0] => sss [1] => helloMysqli [2] => 2 [3] => 3.1 )`

Comment: What does `$refArr` look like after `$refArr[] = $types;` and again after the `foreach` loop where you also try and add the values from `$values` to it, and also, what does `$values` look like before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: i added to my question showing you where I am outputting the `print_r`

Comment: When I add `&` in the `forloop` to look like this it works: `foreach($value as $k => $v){$refArr[] = &$value[$k];}` but i have read not to use `&` and I am not 100% sure what that does to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I add & in the `forloop` to look like this it works:

`foreach($value as $k => $v){$refArr[] = &$value[$k];}`